# Are you not hot ? And Are you hot? How to answer?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, sentence

If I am cold.

Then for the question:
Q: Are you hot?

Answer: No, I am cold.

Q: Are you not hot?

Answer: yes, I am cold.

Is this correct? Or should I say NO for both ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone would not ask "are you not hot?" it sounds awkward but if someone did ask "are you not hot?" It would make sense to answer "yes I am cold" like you said. Or you could say "yes, because I am cold"